# Passing form input from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with a standard razor view with form data. I want to pass the input form data to my controller after pressing the submit button. My view looks like this:

```
@model CareSource.ReleaseAssistant.Models.Prime.Team

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<h2>Create New Team</h2>    
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Team</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Abbreviation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Abbreviation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Abbreviation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedOn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedOn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModifiedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModifiedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModifiedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModifiedOn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModifiedOn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModifiedOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that the information in the form is not being passed back to my controller to be handled by my action method. I'm trying create a new entry in my database using web api. My action method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
               HttpEndPointContext httpEndPoint = new HttpEndPointContext()
               {
                   AuthenticationMethod = HttpAuthenticationMethods.None,
                        Ssl = false,
                        HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
                        //Path = "localhost:32173/api/team/",
                        QueryStrings = null,
               };

               IProcessResult result = HttpConnectionManager.Current.SendMessage(httpEndPoint);

               var response = result.ResponseData.ToString();
          }
               return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     catch
     {
           return View();
     }
}
```

Most of the code in this project was generated using Codesmith Generator and uses the MicroORM called PetaPoco.

Comment: You just have to update view as per given in my answer. Let me know for any help

Comment: Let me know after checking with my answers

Comment: Pass Team model instead of FormCollection

Answer (score 1):

Since your form is strongly typed to an instance of `Team` and you are using that to generate the input form fields, you can use Team object as the parameter of your HttpPost method.

```
 HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(Team model)
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
       //access model.Properties
    }
    return View(model);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your View with the given code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post,     new { id = "form" }))
{
   //Copy your current code as it is here.    
}
```

Comment: I just tried this a few moments ago. It's now passing the form fields to my controller method, but not the data contained inside the fields. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Change your code like this :
 public ActionResult Create(Team model)
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
       //access model.Properties
    }
    return View(model);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Do use Team model as parameter remove formCollection and try